# Sql Connection not inserting data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm currently working on writing an error logging program that will take a connection string and a table name and insert the data that I provide it from other programs into a database. The problem that I'm facing though is that my method doesn't return any values and nothing is loaded into the database. This is a standard class library as well

```
public string ErrorLevelOne(string ConnectionString, string TableName, string ProjectName, string exception, string stackTrace)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string query = "INSERT INTO" + TableName + "(ErrorType, StackTrace, OccuranceTime)";
                query += "Values (@ErrorType, @StackTrace, @OccuranceTime, @ProjectName)";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorType", exception);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StackTrace", stackTrace);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OccuranceTime", DateTime.Now);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", ProjectName);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                return "Error has been posted into the database";
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in connecting or inserting  data into " + TableName + ": " + err.Message);
                return "Error hasn't been posted into the database";
            }
        }
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `The problem that I'm facing though is that my method doesn't return any values and nothing is loaded into the database`; `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` would return how many rows were affected, you're not assigning anything to this. Are there any errors, have you debugged your code, please edit your post.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to write a comment but there is not enough reputation, I apologize.
In this line you do not have spaces before the variable TableName

```
"INSERT INTO" + TableName + "(ErrorType, StackTrace, OccuranceTime)";
```

In the end, you get it

> "INSERT INTOTableName(ErrorType...'

Also, you do not have the square brackets '[~]' in the table specification

```
@"INSERT INTO [ {TableName} ]..."
```

Also check your connectionString for errors, and does catch throw anything?

If this does not help, write, I will try to help :)

Comment: I have included the space after INTO as well as the brackets around TableName, but I'm still getting the same null reference as I was before. I have checked to ensure my connection string is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the exception message. Your SQL is wrong - it is missing a space:

```cs
string query = "INSERT INTO " + TableName + @"(ErrorType, StackTrace, OccuranceTime)
Values (@ErrorType, @StackTrace, @OccuranceTime, @ProjectName)";
```

See the space after the `INTO` ? As a side note, it is usually a bad idea to parameterize the table name; that seems very... unusual. If you *must* do that, it may be worth comparing it against a list of known-permitted values (or perhaps take an `enum` on the API, and worry about the name inside the method), and you should also use `[]` syntax:

```cs
string tableName  = GetTableName(errorTableEnumThing);
string query = "INSERT INTO [" + tableName + @"](ErrorType, StackTrace, OccuranceTime)
Values (@ErrorType, @StackTrace, @OccuranceTime, @ProjectName)";
```

Comment: Hello Marc, I have included the space after `INTO` as well as the brackets around `TableName`, but I'm still getting the same null reference as I was before. I have checked to ensure my connection string is correct.

Comment: @DominikWillaford you realize this is the first time you've mentioned a null reference, right? What line?